# Renaming the Table of Contents doesn't work!

Tags: table-of-contents

Exploring the site, I get only this method in order to replace the ugly "Content" by "Table of content" on the title:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
```

Is there a package missing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8,centering}
 %\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=2in}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 %\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{report} \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents} \begin{document} \tableofcontents \chapter{One} \end{document}` appears to work ok here. Can you reproduce that if you comment out the other packages?

Comment: @MikeRenfro: The `babel` package is the 'culprit' here -- it takes control of `\contentsname` in a `\AtBeginDocument` hook -- so using a `\renewcommand` just before `\begin{document}` does not work. It must be the 'last' thing in a `\AtBeginDocument` hook list, at least it must be put after `babel' takes action

Comment: The `subfigure` package is completely outdated, and `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package (in most cases!). 99 % of the packages loaded here are not relevant for the actual problem, however!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\contentsname` is redefined by `babel` at the begin of the document, so `\renewcommand\contentsname` before `\begin{document}` is too early. Either push this after `\begin{document}` or use `\AtBeginDocument{...}` (as has been done here in the code)

Another way: Use`\addto\captionsbritish` (since `british` is the language setting here!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8,centering}
 %\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=2in}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 %\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

**`\addto\captionsbritish`** -- version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8,centering}
 %\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=2in}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
%\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\addto\captionsbritish{\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That work! I also tried with the "\addto", but that was no effect.

thank you!

Comment: @Batfly: Did you try `\addto\captionsenglish` by chance? That won't work.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but also at the wrong place... 
Both works on my document.