# table of contents rename

Tags: table-of-contents, text

I read:
[I cannot rename table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347682/i-cannot-rename-table-of-contents)
[Renaming the Table of Contents doesn't work!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320925/renaming-the-table-of-contents-doesnt-work)
[Renaming table of content to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610682/renaming-table-of-content-to-something-else)

But I didn't find the right answer.

I would like to modify the default text generated by the command

```
\tableofcontents
```

Someone has the solutions ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's ok now, as you can see below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
\addto\captionsfrench{% Replace "french" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Liste des pièces}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a GOM (Grumpy Old Man) but at my time of life that is par for the course. I think that the generic answer to the question *as asked* is:

The standard LaTeX classes (and many others) use `\contentsname`, `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename` as the titles of the ToC, LoF and LoT repectively. Hence just redefine `\contentsname`.

```
% tocnameprob.tex SE 629526

\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Liste des pi\`{e}ces}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\end{document}
```

Note that the question made no mention of French.